# How can I get the Sheet Options (Left to right or right to left) from Excel JS

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have an Excel file that is written in Right to Left instead of the default layout Left to Right. (You can change the sheet options by going into Page Layout -> Sheet Options -> select `Sheet Right-To-Left`). How can I figure out which direction my page is when creating an add-in? It seems like it should be part of the Excel.PageLayout class, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide any property or method for that. The [Excel.PageLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pagelayout?view=excel-js-preview) class doesn't provide anything for that. You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.